# How can I give attributes to an element on XMLWriter?

Tags: php, xml

Can't find a way to get the result I need to replicate in "Documento", I tried to use

```
$xml->startElement('Documento', 'id'=1);
```

But it gives me an error. The same happens with "DTE" when I write the attributes.
Please help. If my english was bad I can try and give more information.
I also tried:

```
$xml->writeAttribute('id', 1);
```

Here is the code:

```
$xml=new XMLWriter();
$xml->openMemory();
$xml->startDocument('1.0', 'ISO-8859-1');


//Elemento DocumentoID
$xml->startElement('Documento');

//Elemento Encabezado
    $xml->startElement('Encabezado');

    //Elemento IdDoc
        $xml->startElement('IdDoc');

            $xml->startElement('TipoDTE');
            $xml->endElement();

            $xml->startElement('Folio');
            $xml->endElement();

            $xml->startElement('FchEmis');
            $xml->endElement();

            $xml->startElement('TipoDespacho');
            $xml->endElement();

            $xml->startElement('FmaPAgo');
            $xml->endElement();

            $xml->startElement('FchVenc');
            $xml->endElement();

    //Cerrar IdDoc
        $xml->endElement();
```

Here is what i need to get from the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

-<DTE version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte">


-<Documento ID="T33F50363">


-<Encabezado>


-<IdDoc>

<TipoDTE>33</TipoDTE>

<Folio>50363</Folio>

<FchEmis>2020-02-03</FchEmis>

<TipoDespacho>2</TipoDespacho>

<FmaPago>1</FmaPago>

<FchVenc>2020-02-03</FchVenc>

</IdDoc>

</DTE>
```

Comment: No, it gives me an error and says I need to give it 2 attributes when I only need one.

Comment: `writeAttribute()` is the solution to your problem. Please [edit] your question to include the source code with the `writeAttribute()` call (or the `startAttribute()`/`endAttribute()` calls), add the output/result you get from your code and the XML output you want instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
$xml->startElement('Documento');
    $xml->startAttribute('ID');
         $xml->text('T33F50363');
    $xml->endAttribute();
....
$xml->endElement();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!, Do you know how can I obtain this?:
<DTE version="1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sii.cl/SiiDte">